# On limiting JavaScript global variables

Tags: javascript

I am reading a book that encourages the reader for a few reasons, to limit global variables. The technique they recommend is to define a global object variable, like the following:

```
var myapp = {}; 

var myapp.another_stooge = { 
  'first-name': 'Lenny',
  'last-name': 'George'
};

var myapp.properties = [ 
  'first-name',
  'last-name'
  ];  

for (i = 0; i < myapp.properties.length; i += 1) {
  document.writeln(myapp.properties[i] + ': ' + 
  myapp.another_stooge[myapp.properties[i]] + 
 '<BR/>');
}
```

This does not write to my html file, but implemented without using myapp, it works:

```
var another_stooge = {
  'first-name': 'Lenny',
  'last-name': 'George'
};

var properties = [
  'first-name',
  'last-name'
];  

for (i = 0; i < properties.length; i += 1) {
  document.writeln(properties[i] + ': ' + another_stooge[properties[i]] + '<BR/>');
}
```

I must be missing something simple but could not catch it; any direction would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: BTW, if you use a module system, like [requirejs](http://www.requirejs.org/) or similar, you can get away with *zero* globals (other then the requirejs functions)

Comment: Note that your variable `i` will be global too, since assigning a value to a variable not declared with `var` automatically creates that variable in the global scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var myapp = {}; 

myapp.another_stooge = { 
  'first-name': 'Lenny',
  'last-name': 'George'
};

myapp.properties = [ 
  'first-name',
  'last-name'
  ];
```

This should work.. Note the **var is missing** from the second two assignments

Comment: think you mean **note** instead of **not** :)

Comment: @zallarak ..Glad to be of help

Answer (score 6):

You can also keep the global scope clean by putting all your variables into an immediately executing function.

```
(function() {
    var another_stooge = {
      'first-name': 'Lenny',
      'last-name': 'George'
    };

    var properties = [
      'first-name',
      'last-name'
    ];  

    for (i = 0; i < properties.length; i += 1) {
      document.writeln(properties[i] + ': ' + another_stooge[properties[i]] + '<BR/>');
    }
})();
```

This causes `another_stooge` and `properties` to be declared inside of this anonymous function, as opposed to the global object.

Comment: @zallarak - once you start learning JS, you'll find there are cool secrets around every corner :)

Comment: i very much look forward to it!